# Error java.lang.NullPointerException en programa con array

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, nullpointerexception

Tengo un problema con un proyecto de **Java**, estoy creando una factura con varias clases, el programa no me muestra error, sin embargo al correr el código me aparece el error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

No sé qué hacer, la variable en la que tengo el problema es de un **array**.
La creación de la variable Producto está creada en otra clase, con variables de tipo int y String.
Dejo el código del programa (el error lo marca en la línea 61 y lo liga con el main del programa)

```
package clases;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
/***/

public class Factura extends Comprobante 
{
    //VARIABLES
    private ArrayList<Producto>mProducto;
    private float total;
    private Cliente mCliente;
    
    public Factura(int t, int n, Fecha f, Cliente cli, Producto j)
    {
        super (t,n,f);
        setCliente(cli);
        setProducto(Integer.parseA);
        String.parse(A)
        
    }
    
    public Cliente getCliente()
    {
        return mCliente;
    }
    public void setCliente (Cliente val)
    {
        this.mCliente = val;
    }
    
    public float getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal (float val)
    {
        this.total = val;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Producto> getProducto()
    {
        return mProducto;
    }
    public void setProducto (ArrayList<Producto>val)
    {
        this.mProducto = val;
    }
    
    
    
    //METODOS
    public void agregarProducto(Producto p)
    {
       mProducto.add(p);
        setTotal(getTotal()+p.getPrecio());
    }
    
    public void mostrarProductos()
    {
        Iterator<Producto>iter = mProducto.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
            Producto p = iter.next();
            System.out.printf("Código: %d Descripción: %s Precio: %5.2f\n", p.getCodigo(), p.getDescripcion(), p.getPrecio());
        }
    }
    
    public void mostrar()
    {
        System.out.printf("Tipo: %c Número; %d Fecha: %d/%d/%d\n",getTipo(),getNumero(),getFecha().getDia(),getFecha().getMes(),getFecha().getAnio()); System.out.printf("Cliente: \n");
        System.out.printf("Código: %d Razon Social: %s \n", mCliente.getCodigo(),mCliente.getRazonSocial());
        System.out.printf("Productos: \n");
        System.out.printf("Producto: %d", ArrayList<mProducto>);
        //mostrarProductos();
        System.out.printf("Total: %6.2f \n",getTotal());
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuál es la línea 61?

Comment: Al parecer no inicializas la lista `mProducto` en ningún lugar, por eso cuando intentas usarla te lanza el NPE.

Comment: En public void agregarProductos(), en la siguiente línea donde coloco m.Producto.add(p)

Comment: En el main sí le agregué valores a los productos, pero creo que no los asocia con la lista... como inicializo la lista??

Comment: Exacto, lo que te está pasando en lo que te indico en el segundo comentario. Agrega en el constructor de la clase, y debajo de la llamada a `super()`, debes inicializar la lista: `mProducto = new ArrayList();`

Comment: Gracias friend!!! :)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)